# Problem with Boolean Values in PHP

Tags: php, validation, boolean

I've some problems with handling Boolean values in PHP. It is a validation script before storing data into database. I wrote a global validator that will validate and return a Boolean value whether the validation was successful .
Here is my code.

```
    //VALIDATE 
    $isValid = true;
    foreach($team as $key=>$val) {
        if(!is_array($val)){
            $isValid = $isValid && validate($val, $key);
        }
    }
    for($it=0;$it<count($team['members']);$it++){
        foreach($team['members'][$it] as $key=>$val) {
            $isValid = $isValid && validate($val, $key);
        }
    }

    if(!$isValid) { // EDITED: if(!isValid)
        echo "validation error";
        exit(1);
    }

    //END OF VALIDATE
```

The validate function is working properly but sometimes I end up getting `$isValid = true` or the other way, when I try with some test cases. 
Hmm.. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Please provide the test cases that are giving the wrong results. It will make finding and understanding the issue a lot easier for everyone.

Comment: You should reverse it and have `$isValid = false` as default. My guess is that you might be encountering some `null` values. And on your dev machine you should definitively turn on notice reporting.

Comment: The `if(!isValid) {` line near the bottom is incorrect. It's missing the `$`. It should read `if(!$isValid) {`.

Comment: that was a typo .. dint notice .. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check, if this form does the trick:

```
if( false === $isValid) {

    echo "validation error";
    exit(1);

}
```

Note, that `( ! $isValid )` or `(false == $isValid )` in some cases return results, which are at first look wrong. See for example the hint in the `strpos()` [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

In fact, the results are fine, since operations line `!` or `==` try to cast operands in a 'useful' way.

That said, it's always better to user the `===` operator, since it checks values and **types of operands**. Please see [operator overview](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: thanks .. i got the problem.. type coercion ...... 
In validator i was using it wrong `false == $valid` if this was false then the integer value that represents this will be null.. and if this was true the integer value that represents this will be 1 ... So when I was checking with this integer value at some places, the error occured.... even `0 == true` would return true . Thanks for the idea where error might occur ..

Comment: Another note: I wrote ( false === $isValid), not ( $isValid === false ). Why? because if I mistypes '===' as '=', PHP renders an error message. The latter ( $isValid = false ) would silently evaluate. This, I always compare with constant values at the left.

Answer (score 1):

`if(!isValid) {` falls back to `if (!"isValid")`, if there is no constant `isValid`. You probably meant `if (!$isValid) {`.

Answer (score 1):

```
   if(!isValid) {
```

isValid has no dolar, (you need to give variables in PHP some cash) so:

```
       if(!$isValid) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Source : http://bit.ly/1hxDmVR

Here is sample code for working with logical operators in PHP. Hope it will helpful:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Logical</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$a=10;
$b=20;
if($a>$b)
{
    echo " A is Greater";
}
elseif($a<$b)
{
    echo " A is lesser";
}
else
{
     echo "A and B are equal";
}
?>
<?php
    $c=30;
    $d=40;
   //if(($a<$c)AND($b<$d))
   if(($a<$c)&&($b<$d))
   {
       echo "A and B are larger";
   }
   if(isset($d))
       $d=100;
   echo $d;
   unset($d);
?>
<?php
    $var1=2;
    switch($var1)
    {
        case 1:echo "var1 is 1";
               break;
        case 2:echo "var1 is 2";
               break;
        case 3:echo "var1 is 3";
               break;
        default:echo "var1 is unknown";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that your $isValid variable can be changed many times in the loops and by the end of your code simply applies to the last value in your final loop.

You should set it to true initially and then only set it to false IF your validity check fails - not simply assign its value based on every single validity check.

Comment: that's not quite correct; the loop ANDs the boolean with the previous  value and the validity of the current; that ensure past loops - where the variable has been "changed many times" - are taken into account. secondly, you should probably assume the worst (ie: start off with validity being false), then prove correctness. finally, if you don't "assign its value based on every single validity check", how can you ensure validity holds for *all* checks?

Comment: @smcphill fair point on the ANDing of the bool, I obviously missed that part in just concentrating on the repeated setting of the value. As for your last question, that's quite straightforward. Each of your validity checks is inside an 'if' and if(!condition) { set valid to false and break loop (the current approach doesn't permit the use of 'break' so risks redundant looping) }. In this case $isValid is only updated when required and you don't need to use (currentValue && validity check) to repeatedly update its value - which is why I assume true and only change its value when false.

Comment: fair point as well about break'ing after finding a fault - that would save a comprehensive check. I guess it depends on what you're after: (1) to know all the errors upfront (in which case you'd want to track the specific errors, not just $isValid) or (2) to know there's Something Wrong™ with the input... I guess both approaches have their place :)